# spring-boot-starter-mail 3.0.5 - Not provider of jakarta.mail.util.StreamProvider was found

Tags: spring-boot, email, jakarta-mail

I am using `spring-boot-starter-mail` v3.0.5.

I am aware of an existing issue (found here: https://github.com/jakartaee/mail-api/issues/665) in this version which causes the following exception:

```
..Not provider of jakarta.mail.util.StreamProvider was found..
```

However, even when implementing the workaround mentioned in the link, I am still getting the same exception:

```
  public void sendEmail(
      final Invoice invoice,
      final String[] toEmails,
      final String[] ccEmails,
      final String emailSubject,
      final String emailBody) {
    // Get the current thread and its original context class loader.
    Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
    ClassLoader contextClassLoader = thread.getContextClassLoader();

    // Set the context class loader to the class loader of the current class.
    thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());

    try {
      final MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator =
          mimeMessage -> {
            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper =
                new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, EMAIL_ENCODING);
            messageHelper.setFrom(applicationConfiguration.getEmailAddressFrom());
            messageHelper.setTo(toEmails);
            messageHelper.setCc(ccEmails);
            messageHelper.setSubject(emailSubject);
            messageHelper.setText(emailBody, true);
            attachInvoiceFiles(messageHelper, invoice, invoice.getInvoiceFiles());
          };

      mailSender.send(messagePreparator);
      saveEmailSent(invoice, toEmails, ccEmails, Date.from(Instant.now()));

    } finally {
      // Restore the original context class loader.
      thread.setContextClassLoader(contextClassLoader);
    }
  }
```

The error is being caused on the attachEmailSent method:

```
            final var fileByteArray =
                fileManagerServiceApiCaller.fetchInvoiceFileAsByteArray(
                    invoiceFile.getFileName());

                              // On this line
                              messageHelper.addAttachment(invoiceFile.getFileName(),
             fileByteArray);
```

Am I implementing the workaround wrongly? I can't seem to get it to work, if i don't include attachments, the email builds and sends fine so what am I getting wrong?